# Bind 5 items in each row of repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, repeater

I have a set of items coming from the database. Their number may vary. I have bound them in a repeater. Now my following example will explain what I want:
I have 11 items coming from database, I want them to be grouped in terms of 5 items per row.

- 1st row: 5 items.
- 2nd row: 5 items.
- 3rd row: 1 item.

Currently, I am just binding them in a repeater. How do I do this?

Comment: why don't you use list view with defined columns?

Comment: How do you want these items to be grouped? do you mean `GROUP` them `BY` a specific column? and do you want to concatenate them?

Comment: @Furqan Can you provide an example

Comment: @MahmoudGamal I just want them to appear in groups of 5 only. Not group them by any type.

Comment: All answers are helpful. But I accepted the one useful to me. +1 to all others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. It is possible:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptItems" runat="server">
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Value") %>'></asp:Literal>
               <div style="clear: both" runat="server" Visible="<%# (Container.ItemIndex+1) % 5 == 0 %>"></div>
           </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:Repeater>
```

It produces following results for the sequence of numbers:

1 2 3 4 5

6 7 8 9 10

11 12 13 14 15

16 17 18 19 20

Comment: Nice alternative to an <% if %> block there.

Answer (score 4):

if you can use ListView, then you can use GroupItemCount .  some thing like this  [MSDN Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.groupitemcount)

```
<asp:ListView ID="ContactsListView" 
        DataSourceID="yourDatasource" 
        GroupItemCount="5"        
        runat="server">
        <LayoutTemplate>
          <table id="tblContacts" runat="server" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
            <tr runat="server" id="groupPlaceholder" />
          </table>

        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
          <div> your Items here </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <GroupTemplate>
          <tr runat="server" id="ContactsRow" style="background-color: #FFFFFF">
            <td runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
          </tr>
        </GroupTemplate>
        <ItemSeparatorTemplate>
          <td runat="server" style="border-right: 1px solid #00C0C0">&nbsp;</td>
        </ItemSeparatorTemplate>
      </asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stick with a Repeater, I can think of two approaches.

Firstly, you could stick with a flat list of items and make the repeater insert a "new line" after each 5th item. You should be able to do this in the `<ItemTemplate>` with a block like

```
<% if ((Container.DataItemIndex % 5) == 4) { %>
    </div>
    <div>
<% } %>
```

which honestly isn't very nice.

Alternatively, you could use [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/)'s [Batch](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Batch.cs) method to batch your items up into `IEnumerable`s of 5, and then use two *nested* repeaters to render them. Set the outer repeater to wrap the inner repeater in `<div>` tags, and set the inner repeater's `DataSource='<%# Container.DataItem %>'`. This should result in much cleaner markup.

Comment: in reapter control ,can not use Container with if statement

Answer (score 2):

You can try below, I mistakenly said ListView, actually I meant DataList

```
    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5" 
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow">
        <ItemTemplate >
            <%--Your Item Data goes here--%>
        </ItemTemplate>            
    </asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use *nested* Data controls (i.e `Repeater`) and also handle the `OnItemDataBound` event to bind the inner Repeater.

Sample Data Source component:

```
public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static List<List<Item>> getItems()
    {
        List<Item> list = new List<Item>()
        {
                new Item(){ ID=11, Name="A"},
                new Item(){ ID=12, Name="B"},
                new Item(){ ID=13, Name="C"},
                new Item(){ ID=14, Name="D"},
                new Item(){ ID=15, Name="E"},
        };

        /* Split the list as per specified size */

        int size = 2;
        var lists = Enumerable.Range(0, (list.Count + size - 1) / size)
                    .Select(index => list.GetRange(index * size,
                        Math.Min(size, list.Count - index * size)))
                    .ToList();

        return lists;
    }
}
```

Markup (.aspx)

```
<asp:Repeater ID="outerRepeater"
            runat="server" onitemdatabound="outerRepeater_ItemDataBound"
            >
    <ItemTemplate>
    <p>
    Row
    </p>
    <asp:Repeater ID="innerRepeater"
                    runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Literal ID="literal1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
            <asp:Literal ID="literal2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>              
    </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>              
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code-behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        outerRepeater.DataSource = Item.getItems();
        outerRepeater.DataBind();
    }
}
protected void outerRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    Repeater repeater = e.Item.FindControl("innerRepeater") as Repeater;
    repeater.DataSource = Item.getItems()[e.Item.ItemIndex];
    repeater.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server"
  OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_databinding">

                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table id="masterDataTable" class="reportTable list issues" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <asp:Literal ID="literalHeader" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <asp:Literal ID="literals" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </tbody> </table>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
    <input id="hdnColumnName" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" type="hidden" />
    <input id="hdnColumnOrder" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" type="hidden" />


// javascript Function

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ddlReport').removeClass('required');
        $('.sort').click(function () {
            $('#hdnColumnName').val($(this).text());
            $('#hdnColumnOrder').val($(this).attr('class'));
            $(this).toggleClass("desc asc");
            $("#lnkSort").click();
        });
    });
</script>

 // Bind repeater

       DataTable dt = objReport.GetCustomRecord();
        fn = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            if (dt.Columns[i].ColumnName != "Maxcount" )
            {
                fn.Add(dt.Columns[i].ColumnName);
            }
        }

        Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
        Repeater1.DataBind();



protected void Repeater1_databinding(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header)
    {
        if (e.Item.FindControl("literalHeader") != null)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            Literal li = e.Item.FindControl("literalHeader") as Literal;

            fieldName().ForEach(delegate(string fn)
            {
                if (hdnColumnName.Value != fn.ToString())
                {
                    sb.Append("<th width=\"10%\"> <a id=\"btnCustomerName\" class=\"sort desc\" onclick=\"btnSorts_onclick()\" style=\"cursor:pointer;text-decoration: none !important;\" >"
                        + fn.ToString() + "</a></th>");
                }
                else
                {
                    if (hdnColumnOrder.Value == "sort asc")
                        sb.Append("<th width=\"10%\"> <a id=\"btnCustomerName\" class=\"sort desc\"  onclick=\"btnSorts_onclick()\" style=\"cursor:pointer;text-decoration: none !important;\" >"
                       + fn.ToString() + "</a></th>");
                    else
                        sb.Append("<th width=\"10%\"> <a id=\"btnCustomerName\" class=\"sort asc\" onclick=\"btnSorts_onclick()\" style=\"cursor:pointer;text-decoration: none !important;\">"
                                                   + fn.ToString() + "</a></th>");
                }
            });
            li.Text = sb.ToString();

        }

    }
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        if (e.Item.FindControl("literals") != null)
        {
            DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
            Literal li = e.Item.FindControl("literals") as Literal;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            fieldName().ForEach(delegate(string fn)
            {
                sb.Append("<td>" + drv[fn.ToString()] + "</td>");
            });
            li.Text = sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```