# How to force a new line after every row in a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bind 5 items in each row of repeater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327902/bind-5-items-in-each-row-of-repeater)

I am using a `Repeater` control to display certain elements for me.
These elements work off a tabular format, and each one is wrapped in their own `panel` tag.

A user can add/remove variables from these elements as that choose, which in tern expands / contracts the div box.

As of now, the application shows 3 div boxes on a line, then starts a new div box on a new line.

Unfortunatly, if a div box on the previous line expands, it messes around with a div box on the next line.

Is there any way to force a `<br />` after every row in a repeater control?

---

The following picture will help show what I mean.

[image: before and after]

Comment: @Rawling that doesnt seem to be working - And we have an answer that works perfectly for what I asked for - no need to close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a server-side issue.

You should use **CSS**.

First of all, make `<div runat="server">`, and assign a CSS class `line-break` after every 3 or 4 items. This is possible using Repeater's `ItemDataBound` event.

Later, in your CSS stylesheet, use `clear: both` rule on `.line-break` CSS class.

Finally, this should avoid bad effects when some `div` has a higher height than others.

**UPDATE**

I guess you're applying `float: left` to your `<div />` elements.

Comment: How would I know when the 3rd (now panel) is displayed?

Comment: @NewAmbition Use a property of type `int` as a counter in codebehind or whatever. Count to 3. If it's 3, add such class. Then return to 0 and start to count to 3 again, and so on.