# how can I render a div having two Inner div's using DataGrid or repeater?

Tags: asp.net

I want to render below structure using asp.net, how can I achieve this using any bound controls like datagrid or repeater?

Data

```
Inner content
Inner content1
Inner content2
Inner content3
```

required strcture

```
  <div class="row">
        <div class="span6">Innner content</div>
        <div class="span6">Innner content1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6">Innner content2</div>
        <div class="span6">Innner content3</div>
    </div>
```

I got the answer here

[Bind 5 items in each row of repeater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327902/bind-5-items-in-each-row-of-repeater)

Comment: Use repeater - that repeat your patern

Answer (score 1):

Just use an ordinary asp:Repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="uiRows" runar="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span6">Innner content</div>
            <div class="span6">Innner content</div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And populate it with your dynamic data in code-behind:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    uiRows.DataSource = ... // you data here
    uiRows.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: The contents of every span6 are different. so every div with class row will have two divs with class span6 diffrent contents.

Comment: content will be different by data

Comment: OK, is it enough for you to use `<%# ((MyType) Container.DataItem).MyProp %>` syntax?